# Bash program strange display

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting, and I have an issue with `echo` :

1. seems like the lines are printed on screen long after they are executed
2. I am missing the "\n" => all are echoed on a one-liner :-(

What am I missing to keep the formating on the display ? is there a parameter to `echo` that I miss ?

The issue is the last line of the three script example here after.

**useful_functions.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -x base_dir="/Users/romain/Downloads"
function download ()
{
# expect one parameter : an url to download
# use wget to download the file
        if [ ! -d $base_dir ]
        then
                echo "ERROR : [$base_dir] is not a directory"
                return 1
        fi
        url=$1
        filename="$(basename $url)"
        target_path="$base_dir/$filename"
        echo ""
        echo "download($url)"

        if [ -e $target_path ]
        then
                echo "\-> $target_path already exists"
        else
                echo "[$filename] doesn't exist"
                echo " \-> Downloading $filename through  $url to $target_path"
                wget $url
                echo "mv [$filename] to [$target_path]"
                mv $filename $target_path
        fi
}
function sha256()
{
# expect two urls as parameters
# first : a file to download
# 2nd : a cheksum file
# download and checksum files
        echo " - sha256 - "
        echo "sha256 ($1, $2)"
        url_fichier=$1
        url_shasum=$2
        download $url_fichier
        download $url_shasum
        filename="$(basename $url_shasum)"
        f_shasum="$base_dir/$filename"
        fichier="$base_dir/$filename"
        echo "=> Verify shasum "
        echo "=> $f_shasum "
        echo "=> $fichier"
        result=$( cd $base_dir ;  shasum -a 256 -c $f_shasum )
        echo " result = [$result]"
        echo $result
}
```

**script :**

```
source /usr/local/bin/useful_functions.sh
me = $(basename $0)

source /usr/local/bin/useful_functions.sh
destination="/Users/romain/Downloads"
docker=https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg
shasum=https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum

clear
echo "executing $0"
echo "coucou"
echo "\-> clearing console"
echo "$docker, $shasum"
echo ""
r=$(sha256  $docker $shasum)
echo $r
```

**output :**

```
executing /usr/local/bin/get_docker.sh
coucou
\-> clearing console
https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg, https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum

- sha256 - sha256 (https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg, https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum) download(https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg) \-> /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg already exists download(https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum) \-> /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum already exists => Verify shasum => /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum => /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum result = [Docker.dmg: OK] Docker.dmg: OK
```

adding

```
echo -e "That's how use output a newline \n :)"
```

**I still get :**

```
executing ./get_docker.sh
coucou
\-> clearing console
https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg, https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum

- sha256 - sha256 (https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg, https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum) download(https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg) \-> /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg already exists download(https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg.sha256sum) \-> /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum already exists => Verify shasum That's how use output a newline :) => /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum => /Users/romain/Downloads/Docker.dmg.sha256sum result = [Docker.dmg: OK] Docker.dmg: OK
```

But I have to say that I am on Mac

Comment: You aren't assigning to a variable `me`; you are trying to call a command named `me` with arguments `=` and whatever `basename` returns. Assignments do not put whitespace around the `=`: `me = $(basename $0)`.

Comment: bien vu ! :-)  but doesn't change the problem :-(

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net; one problem is that you aren't quoting your parameter expansions (`echo "$r"`), and there may be other similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use -e option

> -e enable interpretation of backslash escapes

```
echo -e "That's how use output a newline \n :)"
```

Check the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) for other useful echo parameters.

Comment: do we need to add the [ \n ]   ?

Comment: I added [ -e ] without effect : [ echo -e "=> $fichier" ]

Comment: @romainjouin Yes you need to add the \n

Comment: I have to precise I am on mac os

Comment: @romainjouin Try **echo --help** for a list of possible options

Comment: @romainjouin if it worked, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I am suspecting there is a non standard mac way :(

Comment: @romainjouin I can't comment directly on your question, I need more reputation. May you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> seems like the lines are printed on screen long after they are executed

This is of course so because you don't let them be printed when "they are executed", but rather you assign the whole output of `sha256` to the variable `r` and print all at the end.

> I am missing the "\n" => all are echoed on a one-liner :-(

The issue is not with `echo`, but with *parameter expansion*, which is subject to [**Word Splitting**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.

A hint at this is written in the **Bash Reference Manual** section [**Command Substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

> Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word
>   splitting.

And so the remedy is to quote the expansion of the variable:

```
echo "$r"
```